# Can Pagedown turn "\n" into <br /> , just like MarkdownSharp's Autonewlines option?

Tags: markdown, markdownsharp, pagedown

I'm using markdown editor with Pagedown and MarkdownSharp.

There is an option "AutoNewlines" in MarkdownSharp.

I wonder how to do this in Pagedown (http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the first revision of this answer included a rather naive approach which didn't work in most cases.
i ported the AutoNewLines option from MarkDownSharp to PageDown you can download it here http://code.google.com/r/marcdrexel-pagedown/

it should behave exactly as in MarkDownSharp

usage sample:

```
var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
converter.autoNewLine = true;
var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
editor.run();
```

Comment: Hi marc - if you get a minute, could you explain how you achieved this?  I'm trying not to use a fork if I can avoid it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027077/how-can-i-modify-pagedown-to-actually-render-newlines-like-markdownsharps-auton

Comment: @SB2055 its just a minimal change see https://code.google.com/r/marcdrexel-pagedown/source/diff?spec=svn89cf815be7922eae7f4e216d811a19e73b4a122a&r=89cf815be7922eae7f4e216d811a19e73b4a122a&format=side&path=/Markdown.Converter.js&old_path=/Markdown.Converter.js&old=3151a581819f39123b0b5fd1ca9e26cebdcaa873

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible through the `postSpanGamut` hook provided by the Markdown Converter in Pagedown. This is the code I am using:

```js
function nl2br(text) {

    // Replace new lines with <br/> tags to preserve formatting for users that are 
    // not used to markdown swallowing single line breaks.
    return text.replace(/\n/g, " <br>\n");
}

var converter = new Converter();
converter.hooks.chain("postSpanGamut", nl2br);
```

It is important to use the postSpanGamut hook rather than a more general `preConversion` hook as the postSpanGamut only runs on the contents of text blocks and there doesn't not mess up list formatting and other aspects of markdown.

More information in the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown#preSpanGamut_and_postSpanGamut).

Comment: I doubt this works: "a\nb\nc\nd".replace(/[^(<br/?>)]\n/g, " <br>"); yields " <br>b\n<br>d" and I don't understand yet the voodoo why it does so.

Comment: ok, you dispose of anything that is before a newline and replace it by a " <br>" unless the line already ends in a <br>.

Comment: matching "not [some word]" is anything but easy with regex and so my solution for now is `text.replace(/([^(>)])\n/g, "$1<br>\n");`

Comment: @Giszmo, thanks for bringing this up. You're right that the `[^]` is for not matching sets of characters rather than words. It worked in simple tests so I ran with it but I suspect it needs to be revisited. Python has `(?!...) syntax for not matching words but I suspect that is a Python extension.

Comment: Actually, javascript has that too but it is for testing the words after matches not before them. We can match only `<br/>` tags with `\n` afterwards, but not only `\n` with `<br/>` before them.

Comment: I've just updated the code to a simple `text.replace`. That seems to work and I've forgotten why I may have decided it didn't. If there is a failing example I'd be interested in explore further.